# Reference for simplicity of the principal eigenvalue of the Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

i'm currently searching for a proper reference or proof to see that the first eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ of
\begin{equation*}
 - \Delta u = \lambda u  \text{ in } \Omega, \\
u \in H^1(\Omega),
\end{equation*}
(in a weak sense in the Sobolev-space) with homogenious Neumann or Dirichlet boundary conditions is simple in the case of a bounded and connected Domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (where we assume $\Omega$ to be a Lipschitz-Domain in the Neumann-case, so that the outer normals are well-defined).

The only proofs i've seen to far all use the assumption that the boundary $\partial \Omega$ is smooth. Because than we have enough regularity for the eigenfunctions to be in $C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ and can show by using the strong [Maximum-Principle](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~bk313/lecture3.pdf) , that we can assume the corresponding eigenfunctions of the first eigenvalue to be strict positive. And because two such strict positive eigenfunction can't be orthogonal in $L_2(\Omega)$, we have that the corresponding eigenspace is indeed one-dimensional.

But what about results without the smooth boundary?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you find that in Gilbarg-Trudinger chapter ...7 or 8? The main point is to show that $|u|$ also minimize the Dirichlet energy.